# Disable Firebase data collection in a library module?

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-library, firebase-analytics

from [Configure Analytics Data Collection and Usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android):

> In some cases, you may wish to temporarily or permanently disable
>   collection of Analytics data, such as to collect end-user consent or
>   to fulfill legal obligations. Google Analytics offers multiple options
>   for disabling and deactivating Analytics collection. Used together,
>   they support many typical use cases.
>
> Temporarily disable collection: If you wish to temporarily disable
>   Analytics collection, such as to get end-user consent before
>   collecting data, you can set the value of
>   firebase_analytics_collection_enabled to false in your app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml in the application tag.

Does it mean that if I want to disable data collection and ad ID featues I need to add

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="false" />
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

to every AndroidManifest.xml file? Including the one in my library (com.android.library) module?

Comment: I think, you only need to add the meta-data tag for disabling data collection in your app's AndroidManifest.xml file, not in other libraries.

Comment: Note that the first meta-data tag as written does not disable Analytics data collection. You are setting "firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" to false, which does not deactivate it.  To deactivate Analytics data collection, set that flag to true.